# Overlaying Ddivs without Absolute?

Tags: css

I have a ten content divisions within a container, I need them to overlap but I also need the content divs to remain children of the parent div as I need the container div to follow thier heights.

The content divs are currently positioned off screen and the container they are in have overflow:hidden; and will be called in by an external jquery script.

I have z-indexed each div to be postioned in numerical order 1-10.

Is there a way to achieve this? This is the main class I am using for the ten content divs,

```
.panel {
   width:85%;
   padding:2%;
   margin:3%;
   right:-100%;

       position: relative;
   z-index:100;

       color: white;
   background: #2F2F2F;

       -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   border-radius: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a [Fiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It would be rather messy.

Comment: Sometimes, restart from the beginning can help find the solution! ^^ Re order your HTML and CSS (use the panel class instead of an id per div for global styles), and post again!

Comment: I could use Display:none but that would make all the text within the divs non accessible by screen readers :/

Comment: Or you can set the `height:0px` to hide element! (Just an idea, needs further investigation)

Comment: the main issue is keeping the container (parent) responsive to the height of the content (child). Hidding the divs wont really effect the flow of the document whereas display:none will remove the content entirely from the flow of the document until needed.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for you is :

Keeping the container (parent) responsive to the `height` of the content (child).
Hidding the divs wont really effect the flow of the document whereas `display:none` will remove the content entirely from the flow of the document until needed.
Good job